# Orchard CMS 1.10.2 TinyMCE configuration changes

Tags: javascript, iis, tinymce-4, orchardcms-1.10

After an upgrade of Orchard CMS from 1.8 to 1.10.2, (and subsequent upgrade to TinyMCE4), I am trying to reconfigure TinyMCE to apply some custom configuration options.

However, any changes made to Modules\TinyMCE\Scripts\orchard-tinymce.js aren't being reflected in the TinyMCE editor in the Orchard interface. I've tried restarting the IIS Site after a change, but no luck.

Do you need to do anything else explicitly to get TinyMCE to read configuration changes?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Browser was caching some TinyMCE resources, so deleting browser cache and reloading the page solved the issue.